# How to use different datatypes in a case statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which I am using for filtering, sorting and server-side pagination.

The filtering and sorting is working fine as expected but the sorting is giving me some trouble due to there being different datatypes sorted.

This is the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllData_filtered]
    @PageNumber int,    
    @PageSize int,
    @sortOrder nvarchar(max) = '1',    
    @sortField nvarchar(max),
    @UserId nvarchar(max),
    @FirstName nvarchar(max),
    @SkillNames nvarchar(max)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT
        *, 
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS 'TotalRecords' 
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             m.UserId AS UserId, 
             m.FirstName AS FIRSTNAME,
             (SELECT DISTINCT 
                  STUFF((SELECT ',' + s.skillname 
                         FROM MST_Skills s 
                         WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar, s.id) IN (SELECT val FROM dbo.f_split(m.SkillIds, ',')) 
                         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')) AS SkillNames,
             CAST(0 AS BIT) AS IsAllocated 
         FROM 
             MST_Users m) AS filteredTable
    WHERE 
        UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM Mentors)
        AND (@FirstName IS NULL OR FIRSTNAME LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%')
        AND (@SkillNames IS NULL OR SkillNames LIKE '%' + @SkillNames + '%')
        AND (@UserId IS NULL OR CAST(UserId AS nvarchar) LIKE '%' + @UserId + '%')
    ORDER BY 
        CASE 
            WHEN @sortOrder = '1' 
                THEN 
                    CASE @sortField
                        WHEN 'FirstName' THEN FIRSTNAME
                        WHEN 'SkillNames' THEN SkillNames
                        WHEN 'UserId ' THEN UserId
                        ELSE UserId 
                    END
        END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @sortOrder = '-1' THEN 
            CASE @sortField
                WHEN 'UserId ' THEN UserId
                WHEN 'FirstName' THEN FirstName
                WHEN 'SkillNames' THEN SkillNames
                ELSE UserId 
            END
        END DESC

        OFFSET (@PageNumber * @PageSize) ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
END
```

Here the `UserId` column is a `bigint` column and the rest are `nvarchar`. Whenever the stored procedure is executed and the `@sortField` is `FirstName` or `SkillNames`, it throws an error

> Cannot convert from nvarchar to bigint.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

I tried casting it in same datatype (i.e nvarchar) but then the `UserId` returns data like 1,11,12,..,100,111,etc instead of 1,2,3,4

Comment: It is a `CASE` expression, and it returns a scalar value; they must all be the same data type. You cannot return different data types from a `CASE` expression; the resulting data type is determined by data type precedence.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble of asking why your query is slow in a couple of weeks (days?) and just convert this query to dynamic sql, this will simplify your ORDER BY issues as well. Also, read this: https://thwack.solarwinds.com/groups/data-driven/b/blog/posts/backtobasics-an-updated-kitchen-sink-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use dynamic sql. See [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-sql-in-sql-server/) and search for `sp_executesql`.

That being said, you cannot mix data types inside case expression. However, you can list each column in the `order by` clause separately. The following should produce the expected result:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder =  '1' AND @sortField = 'FirstName'  THEN FirstName  END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = '-1' AND @sortField = 'FirstName'  THEN FirstName  END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder =  '1' AND @sortField = 'SkillNames' THEN SkillNames END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = '-1' AND @sortField = 'SkillNames' THEN SkillNames END DESC,
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it's working quite well. I just wanted some more ideas about how it can be achieved. Still, thanks for the answer

Comment: You're welcome, but do consider the dynamic sql option along with `sp_executesql`. That will give you better execution plan and better plan caching (e.g. it'll create three plans for filtering on first name, last name and both, each one optimized separately).

Answer (score 0):

This is answer is more along the lines of a trick, or even a hack.  As the comment above by @ThomA states, all branches of a `CASE` expression need to have the same type.  You can achieve this by casting the `UserId` to text and then left padding with some number (say 10) of zeroes.  This means that, when used for sorting, the `UserId` column would sort as text.  However, since it is now fixed width, left padded with zeroes, a lexicographical sort should agree with a numeric sort.

```sql
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = '1' THEN 
        CASE @sortField
            WHEN 'FirstName' THEN FIRSTNAME
            WHEN 'SkillNames' THEN SkillNames
            WHEN 'UserId'
            THEN CAST(RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(UserId AS varchar(10)), 10) AS varchar(10))
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @sortOrder = '-1' THEN 
        CASE @sortField
            WHEN 'UserId'
            THEN CAST(RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(UserId AS varchar(10)), 10) AS varchar(10))
            WHEN 'FirstName' THEN FirstName
            WHEN 'SkillNames' THEN SkillNames
        END
    END DESC
```

Sort order for the `UserId`:

```
0000000001
0000000004
0000000010
0000000011
0000000053
0000000101
```

Comment: I don't think `RIGHT('0000000000' + ISNULL(UserId, ''), 10)` does what you want, since UserId isn't cast to varchar ahead of calculations, it will keep as INT which will lead to no padding added

Comment: @siggemannen You were right; I edited my answer.